# Using Swagger + Java REST APIs

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard

How can I annotate my REST API requiring user authentication such that the swagger page reflects the inputs properly?

So far here is my Java code:

```
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Requires Authentication. Updates a user",
        notes = "Requires Authentication. Updates a user",
        response = BaseResponse.class
)
@Path("/updateUser")
@POST
public BaseResponse updateUser(@Auth UserPrincipal userPrincipal, @ApiParam(value = "user request", required = true) User userRequest) {
```

However this shows up in swagger as:

[image]

What additional annotations do I need to add to my REST method to work?

Comment: are you using OAuth ? and do you want to add Authorization header?

Comment: Doesn't matter to me as long as it is usable within Swagger UI

Answer (score 2):

Ok at least with dropwizard-swagger which supports OpenAPI v2, use these annotations over the class:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(
        apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {
                @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(key = "custom",
                        name = "authorization",
                        in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER,
                        description = "Bearer Authentication")}))
```

And over the method, reference the security :

```
@ApiOperation(authorizations = @Authorization("custom"),
            value = "Requires Authentication. Returns dashboard",
            notes = "Requires Authentication. Returns dashboard",
            response = ResultResponse.class
    )
    @Path("/getDashboard")
    @POST
    public ResultResponse getDashboard(@Auth @ApiParam(hidden = true) APIKeyPrincipal apiKeyPrincipal,
                                                 @ApiParam(value = "Calculator Request", required = true) CalculatorRequest req) {
```

Its important to add @ApiParam(hidden = true) so that it doesn't appear in the Swagger UI.

In the Swagger UI, you should see a lock icon now where you fill in the details. Make sure to also include the name of the Bearer token e.g. "Bearer". Now you should also see a lock icon next to the API and you can test it out.